# different result between like and =

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table on workbench which has a `group` column. I run the command:

```
select * from schema.table where `group` like '%IFIF%'
```

This outputs a table. I copy the first field, unquoted, in the `group` column. I then run:

```
select * from schema.table where `group` = 'four\score_and_IFIF_years'
```

and get no results.

Isn't that weird? I cant figure out what's going on. I've tried replacing single quotes with double quotes, using `group` in ('four\score_and_IFIF_years'), and never get any results.
(i need to use this display format to show the backticks in the code)

Comment: Regarding the formating/markdown, for code blocks you can just paste in your code and indent everything with four spaces (or highlight the code and click the `{}`button in the editor and it will do it for you.

Comment: As for the question, it seems like there are either some characters that aren't showing in your mysql client result display or perhaps there is some trailing whitespace or something throwing things off. For a gut-check, maybe run `SELECT LENGTH(group) FROM schema.table WHERE group like '%IFIF%'` and see if the length of the column matches the length of what you copy and pasted.

Comment: I wonder if you just need to escape your backslash `\`group\` = 'four\\score_and_IFIF_years'`

Comment: the double \\ did it - thanks!